# Циклы и замыкания

Tags: javascript, циклы, замыкания, settimeout

Читаю книгу "You don't know JavaScript". Тема - замыкания.

```js
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
 setTimeout( function timer(){
  console.log( i );
 }, i*1000 );
}
```

Код выше, по словам автора, выведет 6 раз шестерку, ибо

> Все функции обратного вызова функции timeout запускаются прямо после завершения цикла

Проблема была решена следующим образом:

```js
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
 (function(j){
  setTimeout( function timer(){
   console.log( j );
  }, j*1000 );
 })( i );
}
```

Аргумент анонимной функции `j` перенял ссылку на глобальное `i`. Это ок. Но вот следующее меня очень смущает:

```js
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
 setTimeout( function timer(){
  console.log( i );
 }, i*1000 );
}
```

Осознаю разницу между `let` и `var`. С `let` переменная `i` видима только для своего блока. В данном случае для цикла. В то время, как `var` глобален. С ним можно получить `i` вне блока. Но почему в последнем примере `setTimeout` не сработал после цикла, как было озвучено выше. Ведь вся разница с самым первым примером кода и последним в доступе `i` вне блока `for`. Я думал, что замыканием внутри анонимной функции и решается проблема запуска `setTimeout` после цикла, а не во время него. Так почему при условии глобального `i` `setTimeout` запустился после цикла, а при локальной `i` `setTimeout` запускается при каждой итерации цикла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout в любом случае асинхронный и всегда запустится позже цикла. Разница в том, что с let эта переменная не одна, а создается другая новая на каждый шаг цикла, и функция в таймауте каждый раз обращается к разным переменным, а не к одной изменяемой.

Цитата из https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const:

> При использовании в цикле, для каждой итерации создаётся своя
>   переменная.
>
> Переменная var – одна на все итерации цикла и видна даже после цикла:
>
> for(var i=0; i<10; i++) { /* … */ }
>
> alert(i); // 10 С переменной let – всё по-другому.
>
> Каждому повторению цикла соответствует своя независимая переменная
>   let. Если внутри цикла есть вложенные объявления функций, то в
>   замыкании каждой будет та переменная, которая была при соответствующей
>   итерации.

Comment: То есть, в примере с var, цикл дойдет до конца и тогда всем setTimeout'ам раздастся одна-единственная переменная i, которая по завершению цикла будет равна 6. При let, на каждой итерации создается НОВАЯ i с другим значением и выдается одному setTimeout'у и отправляет его в стек. И так, пока цикл не закончится с этим пересозданием i и его раздачей каждому setTimeout'у. Правильно понял?

Comment: Всё правильно .